# Struggling with URL Parameters

Tags: javascript, url, parameters

I need an advice regarding URL parameters. Sometimes when I click a button which switches the page from page 1 to page 2, it removes some GET parameters values.

Here is an example for an `<a>` tag:
`<a href="/forms/page_name/dashboard.php?page=page1&pg=<?=$_GET['pg']?>&type=fa&emp=<?=$_GET['emp']"> Name of Link </a>`

when I click that link, `&pg` and other parameters are now empty except the `dashboard.php`. So I manually code it through javascript just to do it easier like this:

```
$('.leave_info').each(function(index, element){
      $(element).dblclick(function(e){
          let pg = $(this).val()
          let page = $(this).data('page')
          let type = $(this).data('type')
          let emp = $(this).data('emp')
          let super_id = $(this).data('id')

          window.location.href ="/forms/leaver/dashboard.php?page=page1&type="+type+"&pg="+pg+"&emp="+emp
     })
})
```

Thanks for the help...

Comment: Sounds like an X/Y problem. If you lose parameters, it is possibly on the server. It is hard to understand what you are actually asking

Comment: Also you do not need the each: `$('.leave_info').on("dblclick",function(e){`

Comment: yeahh sorry, it's too hard to explain @mplungjan

Comment: there's a lot of elements with the same class ```.leave_info``` which I need to be clicked one by one so I used that function, do you know any other shorthands for that code ?

Comment: `$('.leave_info').on("dblclick",function(e){` will assign the click to all elements with that class. That is how jQuery works

Comment: thanks @mplungjan you are helpful today, I'll try that now....

Comment: @NagonusLrak try to ask the network admin or check in your ```.htaccess``` , you might see some rules there, maybe it blocks some url parameters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking how to construct a new URL keeping (most of) the GET parameters in a better way, you can use `URL` and `URLSearchParams` objects.

```js
// parse the current GET parameters
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
// modify the parameters, if needed, using `.append`, `.delete` and `.set`
params.set("newkey", "newval")
// construct the new URL
const newurl = new URL("/forms/leaver/dashboard.php?" + params, window.location)
// if you need it as string, just toString it, or use `.href`:
console.log(newurl.href)
```

(Obviously, the stack snippet won't originally have any GET arguments, so you can't see how they are preserved by running it in here.)

If you just want to redirect to the same page by modifying some of the params, this is even easier (don't actually run this here, as it will try to redirect the snippet):

```js
// parse the current GET parameters
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
// modify the parameters, if needed, using `.append`, `.delete` and `.set`
params.set("newkey", "newval")
// replace the current URL's search params, which triggers reload
window.location.search = params
```

Comment: Up for this, I would like to use your code and apply it to ours. Can I take your permission? I needed it ...

Comment: As is written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing), the code in this answer is implicitly licensed under [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/). However, one might even argue that this is just demonstrating the normal usage of `URL` and `URLSearchParams`, and as such it cannot even be licensed, as it is too general.

Comment: Thanks for an additional info. @Amadan